# Unity Tweak Tool, Text Scaling Factor doesn't "stick"

Tags: scaling

I'm trying to set text scaling to 1.2, but it keeps "reverting" to 1.56 (way too big). If I click the [Restore Defaults] button, it goes back to 1.00 and that DOES stick.

Funny, I've had this working previously in 15.10, but now in 16.04, it's being a bit freaky!

My first thought was permissions, so I did

```
sudo chown -R me:me /home/me
```

just to be sure I had rights to everything. Didn't help. Maybe something is read-only that shouldn't be? Not at all sure where to look for that.

Cheers, & thanks for any help.